# How to solve the performance warning while adding a dataframe in list in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have created a for loop and i am getting a dataframe(given below) as an output. I am appending every outputs to a blank list. I am getting the outputs but with an performance warning as:

## PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting array of DateOffsets to Series not vectorized

output dataframe:

Intercept     Slope
0   3.008165 -0.001024
Intercept     Slope
0   2.153798  0.001749

Code:

```
coeff = []

for x in something:
    #do something
    reg_df = DataFrame({"Slope":slope,"Intercept":intercept})
    coeff.append(reg_df)
```

Why i am getting that Warning ?

How can i solve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think better is append values to list and call `DataFrame` constructor only once:

```
L = []
for x in range(2):
    #do something
    slope = x * 2
    intercept = x ** 2
    L.append({"Slope":slope,"Intercept":intercept})

print (L)
[{'Slope': 0, 'Intercept': 0}, {'Slope': 2, 'Intercept': 1}]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
   Intercept  Slope
0          0      0
1          1      2
```

Another similar solution:

```
L = []
for x in range(2):
    #do something
    slope = x * 2
    intercept = x ** 2
    L.append([slope,intercept])

print (L)
[[0, 0], [2, 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Intercept','Slope'])
print (df)
   Intercept  Slope
0          0      0
1          2      1
```

Comment: After using the 1st method, i am getting all the values in individual lists?

Comment: I think in first method get dictioanries in list, in second get lists in list

Comment: after converting them to a dataframe, i am getting the outputs as                      Slope        Intercept
0    [-0.00102418207681]  [3.00816500711]

Comment: Is possible add mre code? Because i cannot simulate your problem.

Comment: If i am running your code, then in for loop only first result is being stored not others. can you please tell me why??

Comment: Hard to answer without your rel code. First idea - output `L` is defined before loop for?